# like button on click ajax not working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I want to make an ajax request on click with jquery, but it's not working:

This is what I have:

The button:

```
$photos_box .= '<a id="' . $imgID . '" class="like_button">' . $like . '</a>';
```

Maybe there's an error in the script:

```
// Like function
$('.like_button').click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('liked');

    var status = '';
    if ($(this).hasClass('liked')) {
        status = 'like';
        $(this).html('Ya no me gusta');
        console.log('like_works');
    } else {
        status = 'unlike';
        $(this).html('Me gusta');
        console.log('unlike_works');
    }

    var data = {
        img_id : this.id,
        sta    : status
    };

    $.ajax({
        type : 'POST',
        url  : '/includes/like.php',
        data : data
    }).done(function(reslike) {
        if (reslike == 1) console.log('ajax_works');
    });
});
```

And this is the like.php file:

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {

    sec_session_start();

    // User id
    if (login_check($mysqli) == true) {
        $user_id = $_SESSION['user_id'];
    }

    $img_id = $_POST['img_id'];
    $status = $_POST['sta'];

    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT * FROM img_likes WHERE img_id = ? AND user_id = ?");
    $stmt->bind_param("ii", $img_id, $user_id);
    $stmt->execute();

    $result = $stmt->get_result();
    $usr_likes = $result->num_rows;

    if ($status == 'like') {
        if ($usr_likes == 0) {
            $stmt->close();

            $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO img_likes (img_id, user_id) VALUES(?, ?)");
            $stmt->bind_param("ii", $img_id, $user_id);
            $stmt->execute();
        }
    }

    else if ($status == 'unlike') {
        if ($usr_likes != 0) {
            $stmt->close();

            $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("DELETE FROM img_likes WHERE img_id = ? AND user_id = ?");
            $stmt->bind_param("ii", $img_id, $user_id);
            $stmt->execute();
        }
    }
}
```

At last! Thanks to everyone. Hope my code help someone.

Comment: And the line with the button in the HTML is echoed with PHP right, otherwise concantenating in variables wouldn't work ?

Comment: Start some basic debugging... On the JS side, use the `error` callback of the AJAX, and on the PHP side, start `var_dump(var);die();`ing  everything sequentially...

Comment: Yes, ofc the html is stored in a variable: $photos_box .= '<a>'; and then echo $photos_box;

Comment: I just have to note that you could cut that javascript in half, at least -> **http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/ap7ww94p/**

Comment: It doesn't look like your PHP script is ever returning anything, but you seem to expect to get `1` back ?

Comment: In your new jquery script the text it's not changing. Is it necessary that the PHP script return something?

Comment: `id=" <?php echo $imgID; ?>"`

Comment: I had a typo, you should really have the console open when working with things like this -> **http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/ap7ww94p/1/**

Comment: It seems the text it's not changing :( http://jsfiddle.net/ap7ww94p/6/

Comment: I can tell you that this is useless: `$(this).hasClass('like_button') ? 'unlike' : 'like'`... **(1)** You enter this click-function by clicking on an element with `.like_button`, then **(2)** you remove that class using `.toggleClass`, and then **(3)** you check if the element has that class that you just removed... That if-clause will always return false, because the next time you click that element (after you have removed the class) it won't execute this click-function anymore, since the element doesn't have the class anymore so it doesn't match the selector

Comment: In that case how can I do what I want?

Comment: @ChazyChaz have an unlike class and replace the like button class with the unlike button class. Then check for like or unlike button. Change the class after you populate the data collection.

Comment: Or use a second class: `$(this).toggleClass('liked');` (this will add the `liked` class to the button. Followed by `sta: $(this).hasClass('liked') ? 'unlike' : 'like'`;. (So after the first time you clicked the like-button - when it wasn't liked yet - it looks like this: `class="like_button liked"`)

Comment: [**See this example**](http://jsfiddle.net/1wmtmL4t/)

Comment: Thanks for the example, but I still have a problem: the button text must be in spanish: "Me gusta" (Like) and "Ya no me gusta" (Unlike). How can I do this?

Comment: @myfunkside Could something like this work?? The only problem I see is that the else is not working... http://jsfiddle.net/1wmtmL4t/1/

Comment: Yeah you canged your earlier if-clause to that ternary operator... I would just use an if-clause again: **http://jsfiddle.net/1wmtmL4t/2/**

Comment: I see now you already tried something. Notice that in mine I use an extra variable `status` and only set the `var data` after the if-clause? That's a little more optimized and less code. **Another thing, very important**: you declare the `var data` inside the if-clause. That's bad practice, always declare your vars before so they always exist, and then inside the if-clause set them to a desired value.

Comment: Also, I see you check on the `.html()`. Notice that I check on the class.. always try to avoid checking on `.html()`. Well, you got mine, use it and learn from it

Comment: Wow! Thank you, but the ajax is still not working and I think the problem maybe un the post url (url: '/includes/like.php',). I said the jquery file is in htdocs\js\script.js and the php script in htdocs\includes\like.php... must be a problem because of windows dir. I used to fix this using $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] but in javascript this won't work. Any idea? Thanks again!

Comment: just put `../` in from of the url you have now: `'../includes/like.php'`. The `../` means go up one level in the folder tree, so now it goes from "htdocs/js/" to "htdocs/" and then from there to "/includes/like.php".

Comment: Yes, I tried that but nothing. Maybe is the php script?

Comment: Error could be in the PHP yeah, I haven't thoroughly looked at that yet to be honest.. But what exactly isn't working? One thing I notice is that you expect a response here `.done(function(reslike) {`, but in your PHP I can't see an `echo` anywhere, so how does that script return anything?

Comment: What it's not working is the like.php script that does not recieve nothing from post.

Comment: Hmmm I really don't remember why I put that in the ajax script, I just want to send those variables to like.php and I don't see a reason why the php script should return something, maybe I'm missing something ???

Comment: Are you sure you have your XAMPP set up correctly? I have no experience with it, but I know that executing PHP files locally isn't something natural, normally that's not possible. I know that's what XAMPP is for, but maybe that just doesn't work..

Comment: Try this: **(1)** In your PHP, right after the lines where you store the `$_POST`-values into variables, put this: `echo "$img_id , $status"`. **(2)** And then in the AJAX-done-function, put this: `.done(function(reslike) {console.log(reslike);});`. See what that gives

Comment: lol, the php script was calling login_check() but I just required the db_connect instead of the functions.php which also includes the db_connect.php... the variables are sent correctly, but there's an error (undefined method mysqli::bind_param())

Answer (score 0):

Check the URL in your ajax request, I'm not certain but I don't think '../includes/like.php' is a valid URL  I think you actually have to give it a valid server URL like "http://example.com/includes/like.php"

Comment: Actually it's working fine, but it's also working '/includes/like.php' so I'll use this.